# Regex for converting 001002003004.test.com to an IP

Tags: regex, sed

For a special scenario I've set up an domain address which can be transformed to an (internal) IP address.

001002003004.test.com should revert to 1.2.3.4 as IP.

I've come to the following SED lines but i have the feeling it is very bulky and could be done much easier!
For one case it does not work, although it is unlikely for this scenario to exist i would like to have it working.

My data:

```
user@linuxmachine:/home/user# cat regex.test 
010005248210.test.com
172017170003.test.com
172000017003.test.com
001002003004.test.com
000000000001.test.com
091021000103.test.com
192168123254.test.com
172000000010.test.com
```

My transformation line:

```
cat regex.test | sed -r 's/([0-9]{3})/\1\./g' | sed -r "s/^0*//" | sed -r "s/\.0*/\./g" | sed -r "s/\.\.test.com//" | sed -r "s/\.\./\.0\./g"
```

output:

```
10.5.248.210
172.17.170.3
172.0.17.3
1.2.3.4
.0..1
91.21.0.103
192.168.123.254
172.0..10
```

The 000000000001.test.com doesn't need to work as this is an impossible IP. but the 172000000010.test.com I need working.

I was thinking that the g flag on the final SED would replace all occurences.. but it doesn't seem so. what can i do to improve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, no need to use `cat` and no need to use multiple `sed`. You could use :

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]{3})/\1\./g;s/^0*//;s/\.0*/\./g;s/\.\.test.com//;s/\.\./\.0\./g' regex.test
```

Instead of :

```
cat regex.test | sed -r 's/([0-9]{3})/\1\./g' | sed -r "s/^0*//" | sed -r "s/\.0*/\./g" | sed -r "s/\.\.test.com//" | sed -r "s/\.\./\.0\./g"
```

You'll get the same result (which is not yet correct).

Then, here is a solution that works with a single `sed` :

```
$ sed -r 's/([0-9]{3})/\1\./g;s/\.\.test.com//;s/0+([0-9]+\.?)/\1/g' regex.test
10.5.248.210
172.17.170.3
172.0.17.3
1.2.3.4
0.0.0.1
91.21.0.13
192.168.123.254
172.0.0.10
```

Comment: Yes, I kept it all split up for my own (and everyone reading here) readability. About cat thats probably an old habit ;) thanks for noting

Comment: @Hydrosine I've edited my answer to add a solution that works with a single `sed` ;)

Comment: I see! Thanks for looking into my problem. Interesting to see how everyone solves it.

Comment: Marked this one as answer, as this one is shorter than Cadrian's solution which also works!

Answer (score 4):

I would do with gawk (>=4.0) 's `FPAT` :

test with your file:

```
kent$  awk -v FPAT='.{3}' '{printf "%d.%d.%d.%d\n",$1+0,$2+0,$3+0,$4+0}' file  
10.5.248.210
172.17.170.3
172.0.17.3
1.2.3.4
0.0.0.1
91.21.0.103
192.168.123.254
172.0.0.10
```

Comment: I'm going to use it in a script which can only use SED regex. So I can't use this unfortunately :(

Comment: @Hydrosine if your target system has gawk available, you can use it. usually if g-sed was there, g-awk would be installed as well. anyway, good luck.

Comment: Well my target system only has the following functions available: http://www.opensips.org/Documentation/Script-Tran-1-10#toc70

Answer (score 2):

Same as Idriss but shorter:

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]{3})/\1\./g;s/(^|\.)0*([0-9]+)/\1\2/g;s/\.\.test.com//' regex.test
```

Comment: @cadrian : Not really shorter than my own solution, but I like it :) (so +1)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another more simple approach with `awk`

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<11;i+=3) printf substr($0,i,3)+0(i==10?RS:".")}' file
10.5.248.210
172.17.170.3
172.0.17.3
1.2.3.4
0.0.0.1
91.21.0.103
192.168.123.254
172.0.0.10
```

Comment: Much more readable imo, (i'm no regex guru at all). unfortunately unuseable in my situation.

Comment: @Hydrosine Why, this do the same, just as other `sed` and `awk` solution posted here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another GNU sed alternative:

```
<regex.test sed -r 's/\..*//; s/.{3}/&./g; s/(^|\.)0{1,2}/\1/g; s/\.$//'
```

If you allow the use of `cut`:

```
<regex.test cut -d. -f1 | sed -r 's/.{3}/&./g; s/(^|\.)0{1,2}/\1/g; s/\.$//'
```

`cut` from GNU coreutils can also be used to separate the groups:

```
<regex.test cut --output-delimiter=. -c1-3,4-6,7-9,10-12 | sed -r 's/(^|\.)0{1,2}/\1/g'
```

Output in all cases:

```
10.5.248.210
172.17.170.3
172.0.17.3
1.2.3.4
0.0.0.1
91.21.0.103
192.168.123.254
172.0.0.10
```

Comment: Yes they all work! In my situation the first one is probably useable :) Just have to see which of the different solutions im going to implement.

Answer (score 1):

By step, removing the line (empty) starting with 0 as IP and leading 0 from each number

```
sed -e 's/\..*//;s/\(...\)/.\1/g;s/\.0\{0,2\}/./g;s/.\(0.*\)*//' regex.test 

10.5.248.210
172.17.170.3
172.0.17.3
1.2.3.4

91.21.0.103
192.168.123.254
```

Answer (score 1):

Even more simpler `sed` commands,

```
sed -r 's/^([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3}).*$/\1.\2.\3.\4/g; s/(^|\.)0*([0-9]+)/\1\2/g' file
```

Example:

```
$ sed -r 's/^([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3}).*$/\1.\2.\3.\4/g; s/(^|\.)0*([0-9]+)/\1\2/g' rr
10.5.248.210
172.17.170.3
172.0.17.3
1.2.3.4
0.0.0.1
91.21.0.103
192.168.123.254
172.0.0.10
```

**OR**

```
sed -r 's/^([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3}).*$/\1.\2.\3.\4/g; s/0+([0-9]+\.?)/\1/g' file
```

Example:

```
$ sed -r 's/^([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3}).*$/\1.\2.\3.\4/g; s/0+([0-9]+\.?)/\1/g' file
10.5.248.210
172.17.170.3
172.0.17.3
1.2.3.4
0.0.0.1
91.21.0.13
192.168.123.254
172.0.0.10
```